# How to click anywhere and close a panel?

Tags: jquery

I am have a menu item that If I click it opens a panel fullscreen. Once this panel is open I want to be able to click anywhere to close it. The panel is top of everything with z-index and positioned absolute.

This isn't working:

```
jQuery(".fa").on("click", function(){
    jQuery(".my_search").addClass("opensearch");
    jQuery(".my_search").show();
});
jQuery(".opensearch").on("click", function(){
    jQuery(".my_search").removeClass("opensearch");
    jQuery(".my_search").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xrfhpm7q/4/

Comment: `$(document).on('click', function() { $panel.close(); })`

Comment: if I use that after the first click. The first click won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this scenario, and addressed it in the following manner:

```
$(function () {
    //open the menu when you click on the button
    $('button').on('click', function () {
       $('nav').show(); 
    });

    //close the menu on any click, except the ones on the button
    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        if(!$(e.target).is('button')) {
            $('nav').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You can see it in action on http://jsfiddle.net/v5svskej/1/

Comment: @rob.m I actually misinterpreted your question. I've provided a simpler answer. Just look for the other answer I've posted, as I feel that one is more relevant to your question than this one.

Comment: this was actually working, i've adapted it with my classes but i'll try the other one too

Answer (score 0):

Try using a string when call your function, like:

```
jquery('.fa').on('click', function(){
    jquery('.overlay').on('click', function(e){
        if(e.target === this){
            jQuery(".my_search").removeClass("opensearch");
            jQuery(".my_search").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Just FYI, to close on ESC:

```
jquery(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        jQuery(".my_search").removeClass("opensearch");
        jQuery(".my_search").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: and that is closing it by clicking .fa element which is not what i asked

Comment: Provide a fiddle - jsfiddle.net, way better to help

Comment: I second that - if you update your question with a jsfiddle we'll be able to bugfix much more quickly

Comment: Also, forgot to say (my bad), but in my example, only with a full-width div under your `.fa` you could close it. Take a look now: The `.overlay`, when clicked, will trigger the action, but not when clicked on your `.my_search` div, which is over it.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".my_search").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(".my_search").removeClass("opensearch");
    jQuery(".my_search").hide();
});
```

Edit: This works. I don't know why I didn't think of it sooner...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrfhpm7q/6/)

**Update**

As Daniel states, because `.opensearch` doesn't exist when the DOM loads you need to attach the event to something that is there. As `.my_search` *does* exist (albeit hidden) we can attach the event to this class instead and the click function will work as expected.

Comment: You only said you wanted to close the panel in your question. I assumed you had that bit sorted

Comment: yes the firts part of my code does that. let try adding your second part then to what i have

Comment: it says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're attaching a click handler to `.opensearch`, but `.opensearch` doesn't exist yet.

Attach it to an element that will exist, e.g. `body`, and pass a selector to the `on()` function.

`jQuery("body").on("click", ".opensearch", function(){//do stuff});`

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeq34rvu/1/